# ios14 creating issue in running application

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I build one application for ios and android it is running perfectly in
iphone 11 and IOS 15.But raise issue in iphone 11 with ios 14.
when i install app in ios 14 it is displaying blank screen and just my theme light and dark is working no other buttons are working.
[image]

my configurations are here :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are running ionic react v5 (5.9.3) with ionic CLI 6 (6.19.1).  You should make sure that you are using the same major version for both.